# [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41) Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am unable to store data in the excel sheet because of this error. Even though the data is getting stored in the variable.

I changed !. to ?. in the insert function, then I was able to move forward but the data was not getting stored in the excel sheet.

```
 Map<String, dynamic> data = {
                        DataSet.imagePath: viewImage,
                        DataSet.option11: opt11,
                        DataSet.option12: opt12,
                        DataSet.option13: opt13,
                        DataSet.option14: opt14,
                        DataSet.option21: opt21,
                        DataSet.option22: opt22,
                        DataSet.option23: opt23,
                        DataSet.option24: opt24,
                      };
                      await DataSheetApi.insert([data]);
```

This is where I am adding storing data to the variable data.

```
 static Future insert(List<Map<String, dynamic>> rowList) async {
    dataSheet!.values.map.appendRows(rowList);
  }
```

This is where the error is.

[Screenshot of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zki9L.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check null and then procced,

```dart
static Future insert(List<Map<String, dynamic>> rowList) async {
   if(dataSheet!=null) dataSheet.values.map.appendRows(rowList);
   else log("got null"); //from `dart.developer`
  }
```

Comment: there's a red line under values and when i added dataSheet!.values.map.appendRows(rowList); got null was printed in the console

Comment: Try to check the place where you’ve assigned it

Comment: values is part of gsheets package

Comment: you can recheck the implementation.  cant say from current context

Comment: the code was working perfectly fine up till yesterday, suddenly today it is not working...
and i rechecked the implementation, its all the same.

Comment: Could be issue with getting data. try to debug with add some break-points

Comment: problem got solved. thank you!

Comment: @NikitaGarg I am facing the same issue would you mind to share your solutions?

Comment: I just re-wrote the function again and it was working fine then